# Turning comma separated data from MySql into a php array

Tags: php

What would be a direct way to turn comma separated data from a mysql table, into a simple php array, other than doing it like I'm doing now?

I current do this in a very messy way by selecting data, then concatenating it into a string, which I later use.

I'm using PDO here.

Data is simple

```
locations
-------------------
US,UK,SE,DE
DE,SE,CA
GB,US,DE,SE
AU,NZ,GB
```

**pdo**

```
$d = $db->prepare('select locations a from destinations');

$d->execute();

$d->bindColumn('a',$a);

$count = $d->rowCount();

if($count >= 1) {
    $b = '';
    while($row = $d->fetch()) {
        $b .= $a.',';
    }
} else {
    $b = 'No records to display';
}

echo $b;
```

The output I'm hoping to achieve is just a simple array like below, which is all the rows joined together.

**Desired output**

```
array('US','UK','SE','DE','DE','SE','CA','GB','US','DE','SE','AU','NZ','GB')
```

Can you help?

Comment: How about changing your current code here: `$b .= $a.',';` to instead output an array without the comma which you introduce? If you need the original output as well, then write DB data to an additional array as well as the original data.

Comment: @james Change my current code to output an array??

Comment: You either want an array OR all rows joined together.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there. The easiest thing you can do is use `explode(',', $b)` for the complete string you have now, and frankly, I'm a bit surprised that you couldn't figure that part out after writing all that code.

Instead of concating everying in PHP, you can also concat it in the query using the `GROUP_CONCAT` function. This will introduce a limit, though, since the result of `GROUP_CONCAT` can be at most 32k, if I remember correctly.

Below is an alternative approach. Here, each row is fetched and exploded to an array immediately. That array is merged with (appended to, actually) to one big resulting array.

The advantage is that you are not concatting a big string first, which is relatively inefficient, but in practice, I doubt if you can tell the difference in performance.

```
$d = $db->prepare('select locations a from destinations');

$d->execute();

// An array for results.
$results = array();

$d->bindColumn('a',$a);

$count = $d->rowCount();

if($count >= 1) {
    $b = '';
    while($row = $d->fetch()) {
        // explode each row and append it to the array.
        $results = array_merge($results, explode(',', $a));
    }
} else {
    $b = 'No records to display';
}

// Display the complete array.
print_r($results);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just select the entries and then turn them into arrays by "exploding" them like this:

```
$locationArray = explode(",", $databaseEntry);
```

This will seperate your database entries by comma and add each entry to the array.

Documentation: http://php.net/manual/de/function.explode.php

Hope I could help

Comment: Would that trailing `,` cause a problem?

Comment: Would recommend a rtrim prior to exploding